# Determine the right container to send skb_buff via NetLink

Tags: c, linux, kernel, lxc, linux-namespaces

Currently I am running multiple container using lxc and each one of them is bind'ed to physical interface; say eth1-c1, eth2-c2, eth3-c3 where ethX is physical interface and cX is containers;

Each container is running a user space application which get registered to Linux kernel using NetLink; Now when some packet gets in to the interface say eth2 then I need to send that packet via NetLink to the user space application running in c2 because eth2 is now bind'ed to c2.

If eth4 is bind'ed to c3 then packet received by kernel on eth4 should send the packet via netlink to the user space application running on c3.

How can we achieve this? I know skb_buff contains dev name (skb_buff->dev->name) which will helps me in getting interface name (say eth2 or eth3) but then how to redirect that to the registered user application running in container as I have no other details from the user application other then pid number.